# Mousedown scroll - Stop at exact px point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following to scroll a div on mouse down on the button '#thumb-next'.

The scrolling works perfectly, pushing 20px at a time.

I want it to stop a precise px point though. When the left position is at an exact -px point I want the scrolling to stop and not jump the full 20px.

I have tried the following, with an if statement, but it always jumps to far.

```
$(function($){
    $("#thumb-next").mousedown(function(){
        scrolling = true;
        startScrollingNext($("#thumb-list"), "-=20px");
    }).mouseup(function(){
        scrolling = false;
    });
});

function startScrollingNext(obj, param) {

    var thumbLeft = $('#thumb-list').css('left');
    var thumbLeft = parseInt(thumbLeft);

    if (thumbLeft >= -526) {
        if ( !scrolling ) { 
            obj.stop(); 
        } else { 
            obj.transition({'left': param}, 10, function(){
                if ( scrolling ) { 
                    startScrollingNext(obj, param); 
                } 
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

How can I ensure it stops at the exact point of, in this example -526px?

Comment: Dont declare same variable twice

Comment: thumbLeft. this is just for your info

Comment: Provide fiddle @ccdavies